# Creating a database with MySQL Workbench from existing schema/model

Tags: mysql, database-schema, mysql-workbench

I built a database schema (or Model?) with `MySQL Workbench`.  I'd like to now make it into an actual database.

I've seen Forward and Reverse engineer options and can't find a clear answer on if either are what I need.

How can I turn this into an actual database?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This for mysql workbench version 6.0 and for exporting a **schema**.

```
Select tab MySQL Model
Select File->Export->Forward Engineer SQL Create
```

Place a file name to be exported in the Output SQL Script File, choose your options, next

```
Export MySQL table Objects,  
filter tables
```

Then a file is created which you can import to your database and it creates schemas if not exists, creates tables if not exists.

In the case of models,  you need to pay,  many bucks, for a tool that creates schemas, tables, indexes, cascading, and all stuff associated to an existing **data model**.

Answer (score 2):

As of MySQL Workbench 8.0, go to the menu item **Database > Forward Engineer**. After specifying your database connection and model export options, you’ll be able to create the database you have designed.

See [MySQL Workbench Manual :: 9.4.1.2 Forward Engineering to a Live Server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-forward-engineering-live-server.html) for details.

Comment: This method does not allow you to give a name to the new schema, so you end up with "myDB". It's not clear how to change the name, either.

Comment: @galactikuh Well, I used it a long time ago but most likely I exported it to an SQL script file and then adjusted things like the name in the file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to realize a modeled schema structure on a real server you would use either forward engineering or synchronization. The first is if you have just the model and want it to create all the objects in the target schema(s). Synchronization on the other hand is a means to synchronize your model and an existing schema (two-way). That is, objects not existing or changed in your model are created or adjusted on the server and vice versa. There's no need to create a separate SQL script and apply that manually.

For both action see the Database menue in MySQL Workbench when a model is open.

Answer (score -1):

The official documentation has a relevant article. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-creating-a-model.html

Jump to **step 11.**

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to contain the relevant information without depending on an external website. See [answer] for details.